# Isekai(?) manga where the female protagonist is taken to a fantasy world while sleeping in her bed

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It was a black and white manga. I believe the protagonist had dark hair, but I could be wrong. It was a very darkly drawn manga with horror themes.

In the first chapter the female protagonist is sleeping in her bed and she believes she is dreaming about a fantasy world. Without her knowledge, her bed has done the full bedknobs-and-broomsticks and taken her to a full fantasy world.

When she lands she is attacked by a unicorn, who is promptly cut in half by a character with magical(?) tattoos and also resembles a *Shin Megami Tensei* Demi Fiend.

To elaborate, I read it a few years ago and it was relatively new at the time. There were, maybe, 15 chapters out. From what I remember she was asleep flying through the skies and what we see is her dream. The bed lands and she wakes up confused and sees a unicorn, which suddenly becomes hostile. it was drawn in decent detail. Then the Demi Fiend lookalike came from nowhere and used his tattoos to cut the unicorn in half. He had the ability to move the tattoos around, change their size and extend them from his body. I also vaguely remember that he was subservient to another being from that realm. It was implied his master wasn't 'good'. I don't remember if there was more before her flying into to other realm, but it was in the first chapter and relatively close, or the actual, opening scene.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the protagonist's hair?

Comment: Thank you. It was a black and white manga. I believe they had dark hair, but I could be wrong. It was a very darkly drawn manga with horror themes

Comment: Do you remember about when you read this, or how many chapters it had at the time? Where did you read this; was it online or in print? Do you remember anything that happens before she goes to bed, or was that the opening scene? What about what happens after she is attacked? When she wakes up, is she still in her bed? Is she in a building, or outdoors, e.g. in a forest?

Comment: Not letting me reply to your comment, I read it a few years ago and it was relatively new at the time. There were, maybe, 15 chapters out.
From what I remember she was asleep flying through the skies and what we see is her dream. The bed lands and she wakes up confused and sees a unicorn, which suddenly becomes hostile. it was drawn in decent detail. then the Demi Fiend lookalike came from nowhere and used his tattoos to cut the unicorn in half. He had the ability to move the tattoos around, change their size and extend them from his body. I also vaguely remember that he was subservient to ano

Comment: I'm not familiar with SMT proper, only Persona, but it looks like Demi-Fiend is a specific character from some of the games, and does have tattoos. Just to make certain, it's not one of the actual SMT manga, correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[Curse Blood](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/curse-blood)*. There is only one volume - the series was discontinued due to the author's death.

> "If your heart is stolen, then we will be trapped in the cycle of reincarnation forever, we will borrow your strength, save us, save Payton." Those were the last words a mysterious woman **said to Kyouko in her dreams**. When she awoke, Kyouko was already in a fantasy world, surrounded by gigantic beasts, horrible creatures, and a boy named Solomon with **strange tattoos all over his body**.

The question is an almost-perfect match for the first chapter. A girl wakes up in a strange world while still in her bed,

[image: Different world, still in bed]

and thinks she's still dreaming. She is then attacked by a dragon-like creatures (and later a wolf-like creature - the closest I see to a unicorn in the first chapter is the wolf with spikes through its head)

[image: Attacked by a dragon-like creature]

And is protected by a man with strange tattoos all over his body, and can use the tattoos to attack.

[image: The strange man. Tattoos can come off and also be used as a weapon]